# Count unique combination of the concatenation of two columns

Tags: excel, count, distinct, multiple-columns

I have two columns, they are adjacent, and I need to get a unique count of the resulting values from concatenating the two columns and need to relate them by the value of column A. For example:

```
ColA ColB
A    X
A    X
B    Y
B    Y
B    Z
C    X
C    Y
C    Z
```

Count for A: 1
Count for B: 2
Count for C: 3

I would like to relate them via Named lists, either one list containing both columns or two named lists of one column each. I would prefer not to use an array function, I would like this count function as a summation value. I am fine using vba and custom functions. The columns will not have blank values and always have data, I do not believe I will need error checking.

**Edit**
I can get a count of distinct permutations in the NamedList that contains ColA & ColB. What I can't do is generate an IF statement that tests if NamedList:ColA == 'A'. I only have 3 distinct values for ColA and am fine with generating 3 different functions that test for A, B & C separately. The below gives a count of the distinct permutations of the NamedList show above, which equals 6.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((NamedList<>"")/COUNTIF(NamedList,NamedList&""))
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes, what problems did you run into?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [fairly standard method](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2003-excel/count-unique-with-sumproduct-breakdown/1bc18979-4172-4537-993e-3897f74d6a5b) of gaining a unique count using the [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) and [COUNTIF functions](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34). This can be adapted to a unique-over-multiple-columns byt swapping out COUNTIF for the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED).

[image: Unique Count 2 Columns]

The formula in E4 is,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$99=$D4)/(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$99, A$2:A$99&"", B$2:B$99, B$2:B$99&"")+(A$2:A$99<>$D4)))
```

To adapt the above formula to your *Named Range*, use the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) to peel out the columns from the two dimensional cell range.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX(NamedList, 0, 1)=$D4)/(COUNTIFS(INDEX(NamedList, 0, 1), INDEX(NamedList, 0, 1)&"", INDEX(NamedList, 0, 2), INDEX(NamedList, 0, 2)&"")+(INDEX(NamedList, 0, 1)<>$D4)))
```

Fill down as necessary.

The biggest obstacle when designing one of these is avoiding the `#DIV/0!` error. This is what the appended empty strings and reversed criteria in the denominator prevent.